# Best practices for passing many optional params to a function that wraps a REST API

Tags: python, api, wrapper

This is somewhat opinionated I suppose but was curious if there is a common "best practice" pattern for this.

Say I have an API that I'm wrapping which takes one of many (30+) optional parameters to pass to the URI.  Obviously passing 30 keywords is ridiculous, so what I chose to do is the following:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode

def example(required,**kwargs):
    print('wwww.exampleapi.com/limit='+required+'&{}'
          .format(urlencode(kwargs)))

example('foobar',a=1,b=2,c=3)
>>> wwww.exampleapi.com/limit=foobar&a=1&c=3&b=2
```

This allows me the flexibility to have optional keyword arguments without having to specify them individually in the parameters list, and i don't have to use kwargs.get() a billion times.  The downside is that if I want to validate that the arguments passed in are valid api parameters, I need to maintain a list or mapping of some sort and check **kwargs for membership in this list since i'm not using kwargs.get (or at least that's what i've thought up so far).  Then I can just point to the API documentation for what parameters to use.

Is there any glaring problems that I should be aware of using this approach?

Comment: "if I want to validate that the arguments passed in are valid api parameters" — Why would you want to do that?  If you want invalid parameters to produce an error, just send them to the API; it knows what's valid & invalid better than you do.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "just send them to the API".  As an example, using stubhub's API, if I pass an invalid parameter, it responds without that filter activated, as if no parameter was passed.  This could lead the user to think they have successfully applied the filter as a query param since no exception was raised.